# Parsing Multiline Tomcat Exceptions with Fluent Bit

Tags: fluent-bit

Attempting to parse some Tomcat logs that contain log Exception messages using Fluent Bit but I am struggling to parse the multiline exception messages and logs into a single log entry. I can successfully parse the logs the way I desire, when the log is static and is not being written to and enabling `read_from_head true`; I can confirm this because this is what a sample output looks like (Exception is successfully written to one log entry).

```
{
  "filename": "/opt/tomcat/catalina.out",
  "fluentTimestamp": 1660079524549258200,
  "hostname": "ip-172-22-11-142",
  "msg": "com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container\n\tjava.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input\n\ blah blah blahg you get the idea",
  "severity": "SEVERE",
  "thread": "http-nio-8080-exec-4",
  "timestamp": "09-Aug-2022 01:42:35.475"
}
```

But when I tail the file live, Fluent bit appears to ignore my parsing regex as I only get a "log" statement and none of the other fields. I'm assuming because the logs are partially being streamed and written and my regex is invalid. Here's a sample of my log file:

```
09-Aug-2022 06:36:45.901 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 18109 ms
09-Aug-2022 06:43:04.787 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
    java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2766)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2682)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
09-Aug-2022 06:43:07.060 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse.mapMappableContainerException The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
```

My config looks like this:

```
[SERVICE]
    flush        5
    daemon       Off
    log_level    debug
    parsers_file parsers.conf

[INPUT]
    name                tail
    tag                 tomcat
    path                /opt/tomcat/catalina.out
    multiline           on
    parser_firstline    java_multiline
    mem_buf_limit       5MB
    skip_long_lines     on
    #read_from_head      true
    refresh_interval    10

[FILTER]
    Name record_modifier
    Match *
    Record hostname ${HOSTNAME}

[OUTPUT]
    name         http
    match        *
    host         somelocation
```

My parser config:

```
[PARSER]
    Name        java_multiline
    Format      regex
    Regex       (?<timestamp>([012][0-9])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d\d\d\d [012]\d:[0-6]\d:[0-6]\d\.\d\d\d)\s(?<severity>[^\s]+)\s\[(?<thread>[^\]]+)\]\s(?<msg>[^*]+)
```

I also tried to do a multiline parser but still to no avail:

```
[MULTILINE_PARSER]
    name          multiline-regex-test
    type          regex
    flush_timeout 1000
    #
    # Regex rules for multiline parsing
    # ---------------------------------
    #
    # configuration hints:
    #
    #  - first state always has the name: start_state
    #  - every field in the rule must be inside double quotes
    #
    # rules |   state name  | regex pattern                  | next state
    # ------|---------------|--------------------------------------------
    rule      "start_state"   "/([012][0-9])-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d\d\d\d [012]\d:[0-6]\d:[0-6]\d\.\d\d\d/"  "cont"
    rule      "cont"          "/[^\t].+/"                     "cont"
```

Again, it works fine when parsing it statically but doesn't seem to work when I'm tailing the file live. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? If using 1.8+ then use the built-in java parser. See https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/tail#multiline-support

```
[INPUT]
    name tail
    ...
    multiline.parser java
```